# How to create a form in Django with dropdown items?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I need to create a form which contains fields Group Name, Mentor, Students. Group Name : Text Field, Mentor : dropdown menu(can select only one), Students :(dropdown menu) (can select multiple) . Mentors and Students should be from my users table based on their User group

How can I create such form in django?